# Bundle extra is returning NULL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

I'm having a problems.

In a class "A" I have the code:

```
Intent cInt = new Intent(Add_Product_Page.this, CategoryListActivity.class);
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putBoolean("for_result", true);
startActivityForResult(cInt, GET_CATEGORY, extra);
```

This code is from another class that starts the activity

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extra != null) {

            isforResult = cInt.getBooleanExtra("for_result", true);
            setIsforResult(isforResult);

        } else {
            setIsforResult(false);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Category");

    }
```

I debugged **Class A** and I got the value of **extra** as true but when I am debugged **another class** I am getting ***NULL*** in the **extra**

Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 variables have same name `Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();` and `Intent extra = getIntent();`

Comment: cInt.getBooleanExtra is that a typo it should be extra.getBooleanExtra. and why there is two extra variables?

Comment: Sorry I have editted my code. my mistake but still the value of extra is null

Comment: getBooleanExtra() is not available is Bundle Class

Comment: @Priyanka sorry its getBoolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()`'s 3rd argument(`Bundle option`) is not "extra" bundles.
See [Context#startActivity(Intent, Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)) for detail.
That is launch configuration.

use `Intent#putExtra(String, boolean)` for boolean extras.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Add_Product_Page.this, CategoryListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("for_result", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CATEGORY);
```

then

```
boolean b = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("for_result", false);
```

This is equivalant to

```
boolean b = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("for_result");
```

Also you can check `intent` has extra parameter or not:

```
intent.hasExtra("for_result");
```

Comment: intent.putBoolean does not exist, intent.putExtra would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 isforResult = extra.getBoolean("for_result", true);
```

and remove this `Intent extra = getIntent();` line it's a duplicate instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extra != null) {

            isforResult = extra.getBoolean("for_result", true);
            setIsforResult(isforResult);

        } else {
            setIsforResult(false);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Category");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in **Activity A**

`Intent in = new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("yourKey", yourValue);
            startActivityForResult(in, REQUEST_CODE);`

and in **Activity B**

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        boolean value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("yourKey", true);

    }
```